# Are Night Furies/Light Furies mutants?

Tags: how-to-train-your-dragon

We all know Toothless, who is a Night Fury, but in HTTYD 3 we meet a

> Light Fury, a species that is incredibly close in appearance to a Night Fury, and has almost exactly the same behavioural habits.

The difference between the 2 species appearance includes:

> the Light Furies head is shaped more like a parrots, while Toothlesses is shaped like, a lizard. The 2 species are also different colours. Light Furies being white and Night Furies being black. Light Furies have blue eyes, Night Furies green. The Light Fury has less ‘ears’ than a Night Fury and the Light Furies wings, tail, body flaps and spines are more circular, with the exception of the spines, there just a single line down the Light Furies back.

The difference is so little could it be possible that these 2 species are somehow related DNA wise? Did 1 species adapt? Was there a random mutation that made them entirely different species?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Different species, but uncertain origins

There doesn't appear to be any official material describing the extent to which they differ (beyond the visible) or why. We do know they are different species, since the official website lists them as distinctly "[Night Fury](https://www.howtotrainyourdragon.com/explore/dragons/toothless)" and "[Light Fury](https://www.howtotrainyourdragon.com/explore/dragons/light-fury)" (as opposed to races/breeds/mutations of the same species). We also know that

> they can cross breed, as we see the [Night Lights](https://howtotrainyourdragon.fandom.com/wiki/Night_Light) at the end of the film. Lions and Tigers can do this as well, and they are different species of the genus *Panthera*.

But beyond that, very little is definitively known. Considering mutations are how species tend to drift from earlier common ancestors, and the assumption that dragons are all part of some related family classification, it seems likely that it plays a part.